# xpath retrieve element that occur after parent element

Tags: xpath

I need to click on the element that appears after `<span class="clientadress">`
It can be either `<div class="homephone">` or `<input type="text">`.

I try xpath `/following::` or `/child::` but it doesn't work.
Is it possible to do something like `//following::(div or input)`

Example of element order:

```
<span class="client">
  <span class="clientadress">
  <div class="homephone">
</span>

or

<span class="client">
  <span class="clientadress">
  <input type="text">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
//span[@class="clientadress"]/(following-sibling::div | following-sibling::input)
```

and see if it works.

Comment: This is a wrong xpath syntax. You can verify this on SelectorsHub as chrome devtools will only show 0 matching node even for wrong xpath syntax.
You can get SelectorsHub from here-
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorshub/ndgimibanhlabgdgjcpbbndiehljcpfh/

Answer (score 0):

Try-Xpath in Firefox gives better results sometimes:

https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/try-xpath/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search

Answer (score 0):

Jack gave me an idea and next is working for me:  //following-sibling::*

Thank you all